# View goes to the Table View and the table does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I added animation and a table to the project. The animation seems to be superimposed on the table and it does not work :(
[LINK 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nLm_uwt-AhIrJvib80lLh3ZqBH1b_SWY), [LINK 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Cv4JvadTzJnB_MHG9ksCugnZqVcpgCc)

```
let sportMenu = ["Начать тренировку","Выбрать другую","Советы по упражнениям"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sportMenu.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = sportMenu[indexPath.row]
    return cell!


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "StartTraining", sender: nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var animation: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var settingsIcon: UIBarButtonItem!


let animationView = AnimationView()
let size: CGFloat = 540

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false


    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    let animation = Animation.named("Espander")
    animationView.animation = animation
    animationView.play()
    animationView.loopMode = .loop

    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(animationView)

    animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -120).isActive = true
    animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
    animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
    animationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

}

Comment: Can you provide more details? what are you expecting?

Comment: On the second video you touched row 1 and 2, but in your code you only have actions for row number 0 so, I don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Did you assign delegate and data Source for the table? If not then please update it in `ViewDidload`

Comment: Can you provide me code files? So i'm help you.

Comment: I need the table to work. So you can click on it. It is not pressed

Comment: The video showed that the table worked with a small animation size. And when you increase the animation, the table stops working :(

Comment: Sources of the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eGDZ0Z0Wf_2co2lEV9KOWE4LISC5Vogw

Comment: You people here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Delegate` and `DataSource` assign is missing.
Please Create first the outlet of your table.

> @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

Inside your `ViewDidload`

```
tblView.delegate = self
tblView.dataSource = self
```

May this Work. You can also assign the Delegate and DataSource from storyboard

Comment: Sources of the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eGDZ0Z0Wf_2co2lEV9KOWE4LISC5Vogw